# Convert date format while using date_add function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a variable (order_date_key) that contains the number of days since 1/1/1900. For example, 42711 represents December 9, 2016 or 42711 days since 1/1/1900. I want to convert that variable to the week of the year (e.g., 2016-50)

I was able to convert the variable to yyyy-mm-dd format using the date_add function, but when I try to use the DATE_FORMAT function with it, it returns an incorrect week number. For example, 2016-12-09 converted to 2016-5, but that date isn't the 5th week of the year.

Here's the code I'm using. The format also doesn't seem to work when I use the '%' symbol.

```
SELECT order_date_key, 
       DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_date_key) AS Year_month_day, 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_date_key), 'Y-u') as year_week
```

Sample data: 42711, 42714, 42715, 42720

Desired output: 2016-50, 2016-51, 2016-51, 2016-52

Comment: #1. ```'1900-01-01' + INTERVAL order_date_key DAY```. #2. You loose `%` chars in the date format specification.

Comment: Thanks but I need to convert order_date_key to the week of the year and year. I was already able to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format